# How to use where and join in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I want to join 2 table 'enduser' and 'group'

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('enduser');
$this->db->where('groupid', $id);
$this->db->join('group', 'group.groupid = enduser.groupid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I used this code but it is gives me an error :

> Column 'groupid' in where clause is ambiguous

Please help.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @SankarV Column 'groupid' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message is: it cannot identify the table pointed in where condition.

Change `groupid` in

`$this->db->where('groupid', $id);`

to

`$this->db->where('enduser.groupid', $id);`

or

`$this->db->where('group.groupid', $id);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('enduser');
$this->db->where('tablename.groupid', $id);
$this->db->join('group', 'group.groupid = enduser.groupid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('enduser');
$this->db->where('enduser.groupid', $id);
$this->db->join('group', 'group.groupid = enduser.groupid');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The problem is that you got two columns named groupid in this query after the join, so you have to specify to the reader which one you want to compare.